# Finding replies to my comments on deleted questions

Tags: support, comments, deleted-questions

I am guessing this has already been asked somewhere, but there are 2400 results when I search for the words in my title, so I am asking it anyway.

I was helping somebody and they made one final comment on my answer, then deleted their question (not how SO should work, I know!). I am not sure if my answer solved their question so they were embarrassed and erased all traces, or if they just gave up on it, or what. Since I can only see the first part of their comment in my inbox, I don't know what they said!

Any way to find their whole comment to see if their question was resolved? Thanks.

Comment: For your info, their comment was: *copied the python script you've pasted here and changed the desktop entry to match yours (with it now pointing to testDesktop.py instead as that's what I saved your python script code as), unfortunately still no luck =(*

Comment: Thanks @AndrewBarber. I guess they gave up. Too bad, but now I can sleep at night.

Comment: Try weeping and gnashing your teeth. It doesn't help me sleep, either, but I'll know I'm not the only one suffering.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is there any way? Yes. Ask a mod.

Moderators can search for deleted posts, and can see the comments on the deleted posts. As an answerer, you aren't able to see the question itself (or the comments on it or its answers) unless you're 10k.

It might be *nice* to allow answerers to view the deleted question without 10k rep, but it could probably be abused. Tangentially related: [Show all of my question/answers to me even if they are deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2645/show-all-of-my-question-answers-to-me-even-if-they-are-deleted)

Comment: Thanks. The other thread was interesting too. Congrats on being 50 pts from 10k!! (I have some catching up to do.)

Comment: @beroe 50? I see 40 ;)

Comment: 10K there you have it!!!  :)